# Creating ansible variables based on a string NOT containing a pattern?

Tags: ansible, task

I am trying to create a variable in ansible that is a verification of whether another variable contains a specific pattern or not.

The story is, I need to create a task in my playbook that will prevent images with the version tag `dev` from deploying on production. I'm new to ansible and not sure how to about this.

Previously, I'd worked this other way around, creating a variable that only deploys if a pattern is available.

```yaml
vars:
    archived_image_name: "{{ new_image.registry }}_{{ new_image.image | regex_replace('/', '_') }}_{{ new_image.version }}_image.tar"
    archived_image_prod_name: "{{ archived_image_name | regex_search('.*-rev\\d.*')}}"
```

So this worked to only deploy images with `-rev` in their name. Can we reverse this?

Comment: Making a [`pre_tasks`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#term-pre-tasks) and [`assert`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html) the variable does not contains `-rev` could be a solution.

Comment: How can I assert that it does not contain it though? This is my issue, I dont know how to pass the "not" to ansible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `search` filter to identify if a string contains a substring. Then you can use the `not` operator to negate the result.

Check this example to see how to use them:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    tests:
      - dev
      - prod
      - something:dev
      - something:prod
      - something/dev:latest
      - something/prod:latest
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: String "{{ item }}" doesn't have the substring "dev"
      when: item is not search("dev")
      loop: "{{ tests }}"

    - debug:
        msg: String "{{ item }}" does have the substring "dev"
      when: item is search("dev")
      loop: "{{ tests }}"
```

You should see this output:

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************
Saturday 29 May 2021  16:11:03 -0300 (0:00:00.020)       0:00:00.020 ********** 

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=prod) => 
  msg: String "prod" doesn't have the substring "dev"
ok: [localhost] => (item=something:prod) => 
  msg: String "something:prod" doesn't have the substring "dev"
ok: [localhost] => (item=something/prod:latest) => 
  msg: String "something/prod:latest" doesn't have the substring "dev"
Saturday 29 May 2021  16:11:03 -0300 (0:00:00.079)       0:00:00.100 ********** 

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=dev) => 
  msg: String "dev" does have the substring "dev"
ok: [localhost] => (item=something:dev) => 
  msg: String "something:dev" does have the substring "dev"
ok: [localhost] => (item=something/dev:latest) => 
  msg: String "something/dev:latest" does have the substring "dev"

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Please check the following link to learn more about the `search` filter:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html